# EWS Digitally signed emails have empty body after upgrade from Exchange 2007 SP1 to Exchange 2013

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, email

we have a problem with upgrade from Exchange 2007 SP1 to Exchange 2013. We are using ews to get emails from specific folder. Code looks like this:

```
private List<Item> GetAllItems(string folderId)
    {
        Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(m_Exchange, folderId);

        List<Item> m_ListOfItems = new List<Item>();
        ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);

        FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(itemView);

        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            item.Load();
            m_ListOfItems.Add(item);
        }

        return m_ListOfItems;
    }
```

Our problem with Exchange 2013 is when the email is digitally signed, in this case email body is empty. For other emails its just fine for both plaintext/html email types. Also this code works well even for digitally signed emails on Exchange 2007 SP1.

Is anybody familiar with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem by now?

Comment: No, it remains unsolved.