# UniqueBody empty when Body is not

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have inherited responsibility for a project from a previous developer which takes incoming emails and processes them into customer support tickets.

It mostly works fine but it is having problems with one particular email and I can't work out why.
In Outlook the email clearly has a body (some short text, an image and a signature).  It is a new message and not a reply.
The exchange server version is 2013.

But when being processed by the code below `UniqueBody` is empty, while `Body` contains the correct text.  This does not happen with any other emails I've come across on that server.

```
if (serverVersion >= ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
    body = msg.UniqueBody.Text;
else
    body = msg.Body.Text;
```

What would cause UniqueBody to be empty while Body is not?

Why would the previous developer prefer to use UniqueBody over Body, how do they differ?

Could be related [to this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27149770/ews-digitally-signed-emails-have-empty-body-after-upgrade-from-exchange-2007-sp1)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you request the properties correctly:

```
PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.UniqueBody);
var email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.ItemId, ps);
```

If you do so, the `UniqueBody`-Property should not be empty.

As far as I know, `UniqueBody` should be set by the exchange-server to show you which part of the mail is relevant for your ticket:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877075(v=exchg.150).aspx

If your customer answers later to the ticket-conversation, you only want the new text.
With a new mail/ticket: `body == uniqueBody == "the text you want to use"`.